# Command-line tool to empty a folder in CMIS/Alfresco/Nuxeo/SharePoint/Documentum

Tags: gratis, command-line, cmis

I often want to clear a remote CMIS folder programmatically (from a script).
For instance to remove test files or do some recurrent clean-up.

Requirements:

- Executable from command-line
- Takes a CMIS folder in input
- Remove all documents and sub-folders from that folder
- Gratis, preferably open source
- Works with Alfresco/Nuxeo/SharePoint/Documentum and as many other CMIS servers as possible

Answer (score 3):

I did not find such a tool so I wrote this one:

https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/clear-cmis-folder

Usage:

```
./clear-cmis-folder.sh /the/folder http://the/cmis/url theuser thepassword
```

It removes all documents and folders under that path.
Gratis, MIT license.
Tested on Alfresco.

Comment: I was going to suggest that python could probably do the job and found that is how you have done it +1.